# Deleted driver stil loads on Linux

Tags: linux, drivers

On my Centos 6.8 system, this is my *nvme* driver:

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/block/nvme.ko
```

When Linux boots this driver gets loaded automatically. Running `lsmod` shows this driver is loaded and using `modprobe -r` or `rmmod` I can unload the driver. So *nvme* is a loadable module and not built into the kernel.

I deleted `nvme.ko` file and rebooted the system. Running `modinfo nvme` says it can't find the driver, but the driver still loads! `lsmod` detects the driver and I can unload the driver.

As root, `find /lib/modules -name nvme.ko` does not find any *nvme* driver on the system.

I know I can blacklist the driver so it wont load, but what I want to really know is: **where is Linux finding the driver since it does not exist anymore?**

Comment: It's most likely on the init ramdisk because it's boot-relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to blacklist the module ?

You can do this by adding a line
`blacklist nvme` in a file like `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvme.conf`

See also https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/rescuemode_drivers-blacklisting.html